# Como Exibir Json em PHP

Tags: php, json

Pego um usuário de um BD via API.

```
<?php
require "vendor/autoload.php";

    use Intercom\IntercomClient;
        $client = new IntercomClient(App_ID, App_Key);

    $client->leads->getLeads(['email' => 'kmodas@kmodas.com']); 
?>
```

OBS: já tentei isso:

> Echo "< br>< pre>< br>"; 
>   Echo  $client; 
>   Echo  "< br>< br>";

Como exibo os dados que pegar?

Comment: json_encode e json_decode não resolve? http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.json.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De acordo com a [documentação](https://developers.intercom.io/reference#list-leads), você receberá um `JSON` como esse:

```
{
  "type": "contact.list",
  "total_count": 105,
  "contacts": [
    {
      "type": "contact",
      "id": "530370b477ad7120001d",
    },
    {
      "type": "contact",
      "id": "530370b477ad7120001d",
      "user_id": "8a88a590-e1c3-41e2-a502-e0649dbf721c",
      "email": "winstonsmith@truth.org",
      "name": "Winston Smith",
    },
    {
      "type": "contact",
      "id": "530370b477ad7120001d",
      "user_id": "8a88a590-e1c3-41e2-a502-e0649dbf721c",
      "email": "winstonsmith@truth.org",
      "name": "Winston Smith",
    },
    {
      "type": "contact",
      "id": "530370b477ad7120001d",
      "user_id": "8a88a590-e1c3-41e2-a502-e0649dbf721c",
      "email": "winstonsmith@truth.org",
      "name": "Winston Smith",
    }
  ],
  "pages": {
    "next": "https://api.intercom.io/contacts?per_page=50&page=2",
    "page": 1,
    "per_page": 50,
    "total_pages": 3
  }
}
```

Ficando da seguinte forma:

```
require "vendor/autoload.php";
use Intercom\IntercomClient;

$client = new IntercomClient(App_ID, App_Key);
$leads = $client->leads->getLeads(['email' => 'kmodas@kmodas.com']); 

foreach($leads->contacts as $contact){
    echo "type: " . $contact->type;
    echo "id: " . $contact->id;
    echo "user_id: " . $contact->user_id;
    echo "email: " . $contact->email;
    echo "name: " . $contact->name;
}
```

Comment: Opa Marcelão blz ? cara me retornou o seguinte: `
Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /home/u213882019/public_html/lead/get.php on line 7

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/u213882019/public_html/lead/get.php on line 9`

Comment: Dá um `var_dump` em `$leads` antes do método `json_decode` e diz qual o retorno dele.

Comment: Opa , o do nosso amigo Leandro: 
 ele me retornou um código imenso, más com as informações. não querendo abusar mas como pego somente um campo exemplo o ID. [ideone.com/IY2wx1]

Comment: Comente a linha `$leads = json_decode($leads);`, dentro do `foreach`comente os campos que não serão mostrados também e veja o que ocorre

Comment: o Codigo ta assim: `<?php
 require "vendor/autoload.php";
   use Intercom\IntercomClient;
  $client = new IntercomClient(App-ID, App_Key);
  
  $res = $client->leads->getLeads(['email' => 'kmodas@kmodas.com']);
  echo json_encode($res, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
 
?>`

Comment: o $res está retornando o array, então é só você inserir dentro do foreach pra pegar as chaves e seus valores.

Comment: `echo $res[contacts][id];`  seria isso ?! tentei me retornou  `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /home/u213882019/public_html/lead/get.php on line 9`

Comment: Não, utilize o exemplo dessa resposta, apenas retirando a linha `$leads = json_decode($leads);`

Comment: **Amigos , desculpem a falta de conhecimento** @LeandroAmaral não tenho esta linha no meu código. apenas adicionei as duas linhas que você respondeu e funcionou :D

Comment: Lucas, dê uma olhada como está o código da minha resposta após essa edição. Como a `API` já está retornando um objeto, basta iterar sobre ele.

Comment: **Resolvido** , Muito obrigado pela atenção , pelas respostas que todos deram. por tudo galera funcionou após o Edit e o complemento do @MarcelodeAndrade e do LeandroAmaral

Answer (score 3):

```
$response = $client->leads->getLeads(['email' => 'kmodas@kmodas.com']);
echo json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

[EDIT] Pegar uma chave específica

```
$response = $client->leads->getLeads(['email' => 'kmodas@kmodas.com']);
foreach($response as $contact){
    echo "id: " . $contact->id;
}
```

Comment: Perfeito funcionou! ele me retornou um código imenso, más com as informações. não querendo abusar mas como pego somente um campo exemplo o ID. [http://ideone.com/IY2wx1]

Comment: Leandro , não está exibindo o valor de ID

Comment: Na linha do foreach altere $response, para $reponse['users']

Answer (score 2):

Use o [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php):

```
$leads = $client->leads->getLeads(['email' => 'kmodas@kmodas.com']); 

$clients = json_decode(json_encode($leads), true);

foreach ($clients as $chave => $valor){
    echo "$chave => $valor \n";
}
```

**Edição**: Como pode ser visto nas respostas do [Marcelo de Andrade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/147541/6454) e [Leandro Amaral](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/147536/6454), o `json_decode` não é necessário, você pode iterar diretamente sobre o [objeto](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.object.php) retornado da API como mostrado nas respostas.

Comment: Estou começando nesta área oque passaria em $chave e $valor ? me retornou os erros: Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /home/u213882019/public_html/lead/get.php on line 9

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/u213882019/public_html/lead/get.php on line 10

Comment: @LucasBicalleto Faça assim: `$clients = json_decode(json_encode($json), true);`e tente de novo. `chave` e `valor`  são informações sobre o item atual da iteração sobre o `array` retornado.

Comment: -> `Fatal error: Call to undefined function json_enc‌​ode() in /home/u213882019/public_html/lead/get.php on line 9` .Se quiser adicionar skype. te dou uns detalhes. `programacao.ciclum`

Comment: @LucasBicalleto Consegue criar um exemplo no http://ideone.com/ e postar o link aqui?

Comment: http://ideone.com/ORrncy

Comment: @LucasBicalleto O que aparece quando você executa `var_dump(function_exists('json_encode'));` ??

Comment: como pego o ID retornado do seu Script ?