# Erro ao exibir Json em PHP

Tags: php, json

Tenho o seguinte código.

```
<?php

$email = $_POST['email'];
$nome  = $_POST['nome'];

//Não mexer//
require_once "vendor/autoload.php"; 
    use Intercom\IntercomClient;
        $client = new IntercomClient('App_ID', 'App_Key');
//Não mexer//

//Cria o Lead//
    $client->leads->create([
            "name"  => "$nome",
            "email" => "$email"
    ]);
//Termina de Criar//

//Pega dados Lead//
    $leads = $client->leads->getLeads(['email' => $email]); 

    foreach($leads->contacts as $contact){
        echo "type: " . $contact->type;
        echo "id: " . $contact->id;
        echo "user_id: " . $contact->user_id;
        echo "email: " . $contact->email;
        echo "name: " . $contact->name;
    }
//Termina de Pegar//

//Adiciona a Tag//
    $client->tags->tag([ 
    "name" => "Beneficio-em-Dobro", 
    "leads" => [ 
            ["id" => "$id"] 
        ] 
    ]);
//Termina de Adicionar//    ?>
```

Porém ao executar este código, ele cria o 'Lead' más não cria a TAG.
e não me exibe os dados dele. já tentei passar dentro de "" más não vai.

Comment: Lucas, para mim não está claro o que você está tentando fazer. Se `tags` é um array, para adicionar um elemento você precisa fazer algo do tipo `$client->tags[] = new  Tag();`, mas parece mais que isso é uma espécie de DSL. Será que a API não tem uma função `tags->create` da vida? Precisamos entender mais sobre essa API que você está usando, por acaso seria [essa aqui](https://github.com/intercom/intercom-php)? Poste mais informações.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly a API que você citou é a que uso!

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly quando passo o código assim: `$leads = $client->leads->getLeads(["email" => "$email"]); ` não vai, mas se passo assim: `$leads = $client->leads->getLeads(["email" => "exemplo@exemlo.coml"]);` ai vai normal.
estou com uma demanda de fazer isso faz 3 dias.

Comment: Ok, provavelmente você está feriando algum contrato da API na hora de criar essa tag. De uma olhada [na descrição do serviço REST](https://developers.intercom.io/reference#tag-or-untag-users-companies-leads-contacts), `$id` está apontando para um id válido no sistema? Veja que na API REST também é possível taggear usuários por `user_id`  ou `email`, como não conheço a API não tenho ideia de qual seja a diferença entre `id` e `user_id`.

Comment: Lucas, você não deve passar uma string, deve passar a variável (no seu caso `$email`  (que vem do request post). Muito provavelmente a mesma coisa está acontecendo com esse `$id` (você tem que passar um id real vindo de algum lugar, ou um email de acordo com a API).

Comment: `$leads = $client->leads->getLeads(["email" => $email]);` se passo assim tambem me retorna erro, irei dar uma lida mais ja li tudo :/

Comment: Consegue imprimir o valor de `$email`? As vezes o seu request não está chegando correto (isso é, `$email` não é um e-mail válido). Verifique também na descrição da API PHP se é possível fazer essa consulta filtrando por e-mail.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly , aqui consegui fazer isso , com user da certo mas com Lead não. [http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/147528/como-exibir-json-em-php?rq=1]